Is there not a muddy overlap between the great existentialist questions and the great metaphysical questions?
We all know the fundamentality of these two branches of philosophy. Metaphysics deals with existence as such while existentialism deals with the predicament of human existence.
What I am having trouble with arguments can be made that for an individual human being, if they seek the truth about ‘What all this is and why I am a part of it’ they are seeking to deal with the great metaphysical questions, while arguments can also be made that no, they are seeking to deal with the great existentialist questions?
How can one differentiate the two fields? My current understanding is that by definition (I mean the definition of the two terms I gave above) existentialism is a subset of metaphysics in the same way that ontology and mereology are subsets of metaphysics. Is this an accepted conceptualization or is it faulty? What is the academic consensus on the relation and overlap (if there is any, as I may be mistaken) of these 2 fields?

Maybe true for Heidegger, not so fo Camus or Kierkegaard...

All sciences, not just this aspect of philosophy face logic problems when trying to compare statistical or philosophical answers with individual or anecdotal answers.
Existentialism is about the individual - and each individual might try to convince others of their perspectives.
Meta- is, by design, independent of the individual, a higher layer. A community of individuals, for example, has different qualities than any specific individual. Of course there is overlap, but it is not 'muddy' it is natural.
A similar problem occurs in medicine, with the concepts of EBM - statistical Evidence Based Medicine (which does not contain a definition of cured), and anecdotal (individual) cures, where cured is defined by individual cases. Unfortunately, our current medical systems tend to be entirely focused on statistical clinical studies as substantiated "truths" and dismissal of anecdotal cures as "not worthy stories."
We can find a gradation between individual and meta when we base the meta on statistics about individual cases, but this requires restricting the meta- to specific boundaries, resulting in some loss of freedom to understand the general.

There's a bit of an issue with language here. Technically speaking, the term 'metaphysics' deals with all questions about the fundamental nature of things (including humans). Existentialism and its related schools would certainly fall under that heading. However, by the late 19th and early 20th centuries 'metaphysics' had gained a colloquial meaning of 'grand theory': sophisticated, abstract, and speculative, but detached from reality. The idealism of someone like Hegel did not resonate in a world of rampaging industrial destruction, total war, and other forms of wholesale brutality. So beginning with Nietzsche (and to a lesser extent Marx and Freud), philosophy began to reject 'grand theory' as an empty and paternalistic exercise. Instead, it moved towards discovering proper apperception or authenticity: not showing people how to live, but showing them how to discover how to live for themselves, discarding and transcending the vapid social rules that have been imposed on them.
So, existentialism (and phenomenology, absurdism, etc) are metaphysics in the proper sense that they investigate the nature of human existence. But they are opposed to 'metaphysics' in the sense of grand theory meant to establish universal ideals of human nature.
